# How do I force a page to generate a pagefault on next access?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm64, page-fault, sve

I am trying to develop a routine using SVE.  SVE provides fault-avoiding loads which do not load from memory that would lead to a fault if accessed.  As the CPU does not know the reason why a page is unmapped or inaccessible, it cannot distinguish between memory that would trigger an invalid page fault and memory that would trigger a major/minor page fault (which is usually transparent to the application).

SVE code using these instructions must thus be prepared for stray faults to be indicated and must retry the loads using non-faulting instructions if it requires the data after all.  For example, consider a routine operating on NUL-terminated strings.  A first-fault load is used to load a chunk of the string.  If a fault was avoided only after a NUL character, everything is fine.  But if that happened before a NUL character, we must retry the load with conventional load instructions as the string has been proven to cross into the faulting page.

If such “retry on avoided fault” paths are present in the code, they must be tested.  However, it does not seem obvious to me how to prepare a page to fault (with major or minor page fault) on next access.  If an all-zero page is acceptable, a possibility seems to be to just map a fresh anonymous page and make use of the kernel's lazy page allocation.  However, this is not guaranteed or documented to cause the desired effect.

For arbitrary pages, the `madvise` system call has the `MADV_PAGEOUT` option, which seems like it might give the desired effect, but the man page does not document if the effect takes place immediately, and states that it might not affect certain pages.  It is also unclear if the call works in the absence of swap space.  Success/failure does not seem to be reported unambigously so it's unclear if a unit test can rely on this call.  It would be quite bad for the unit test to silently pass due to the page not actually being unmapped when it runs.

What is the recommended course of action?

Also interested in responses for other operating systems (such as FreeBSD) and in particular also hardware-specific approaches, that may or may not be specific to ARM.

Comment: A colleague of mine did experiments with Linux on x86-64 with functions such as memcmp and memcpy and observed page faults fairly regularly without doing anything special to force them. IIRC, he observed page faults about 1% of the time on operations of 4 KB and above.

Comment: @prl Yeah, but to test the fault-avoiding cases, we need a way to reliably trigger a page fault in a specific page.  Just random page faults don't help with designing accurate unit tests.

Comment: For testing on a specific system, you could use `MADV_PAGEOUT` in a loop and check that you get a boatload of soft page faults, like one for every call if you do an access in between.  Or perhaps `mmap(MAP_FIXED)`, maybe alternating between two different files (neither of which is `/dev/zero` or anonymous) if the kernel checks for the case of replacing a page with the same page of pagecache.  Or `munmap` in between.  Are you *only* looking for documented future-proof guarantees, or would something that works in practice on current Linux be of interest?

Comment: *It is also unclear if the call works in the absence of swap space* - A mapping backed by a real file shouldn't care.  Swap space only backs anonymous mappings, such as dirty MAP_PRIVATE mappings of files, and MAP_ANONYMOUS.  Other mappings get paged out to whatever backs them, e.g. a file for MAP_SHARED.  Or just dropped if clean.

Comment: My intuition based on the man page descriptions is that `MADV_PAGEOUT` is what you're looking for.  It doesn't say anything about possibly-delayed effect, unlike `MADV_FREE`.  It was added later, presumably because of use-cases where an application definitely wanted the page reclaimed *now*, rather than just giving a hint to the memory-pressure algorithms.  (If they just wanted to sync to the backing store for MAP_SHARED and wait for that to finish, they could use `msync(MS_SYNC)`.  Which doesn't reclaim the page, just cleans it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm looking for a future-proof solution as this will go into a unit test that should be correct without further changes.  So something that is not specified to do what I expect could lead to a faulty (as in false-negative) unit test.  A Twitter user has suggested to mark the page as inaccessible (triggering a fault condition) and to then use a signal handler to make it accessible again.  Returning from the signal handler makes the code continue, as if recovering from a major/minor page fault.  Will try that and perhaps write such an answer.

Comment: ... continued from previous comment.  `msync` has an `MS_INVALIDATE` that invalidates *other* mappings of the same file ("*(so that they can be updated with the fresh values just written*").  Maybe that matters on NFS, although probably it can only invalidate mapping on this system, not other systems that have the same file mapped.  (It's a POSIX function, so maybe it's meaningful on OSes?  IDK what it does on Linux.)

Comment: Some systems e.g. coalesce 4k pages into 2M pages with a background task.  If this happens eagerly, it could mean that pretty much immediately after paging out the page, the kernel pages it back in so it can make a 2M page with the surrounding pages.  Linux could realistically do this in the future (or already does so?).

Comment: @fuz:  You could maybe write a unit test for whatever hack you use to play with pages, so you have a unit test for the building-block your other unit tests use.  e.g. with `perf stat -e page-faults` (or `perf_event_open`) to count total page faults over something that runs for 10 to 100 milliseconds, and compare that with the number of iterations made in that time where you expect 1 page fault.  If you're worried about immediate transparent-hugepage coalescing, use `MADV_NOHUGEPAGE` on that region.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html mentions that after `MREMAP_DONTUNMAP`, the old addresses *will* page fault (and zero-fill).  And mentions/recommends a garbage-collection use-case with `userfaultfd` where correctness depends on getting notified of the soft page-fault, so at least if you open a `userfaultfd`, you can be sure nothing has silently prefaulted the page.  I knew I'd seen a Linux man page say that you will get a page fault in some case, but I couldn't remember where until now.  So perhaps remap a page away, and then remap it back later if you want.

Comment: @fuz: `mprotect(PROT_NONE)` plus a signal handler is what I would do.  That seems like the only way to be sure the page remains not-present.  The signal handler can either `mprotect(PROT_READ)` and return, or else `siglongjmp` somewhere else to report the result of the test.

Comment: And if you want to be certain that a page fault does *not* happen, there's `mlock()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I ended up using was to allocate a page without read/write permissions.  On first access, a `SIGSEGV` would occur, ensuring that the access failed.  In the signal handler, I then permit access to the page and return, resuming the code under test.

While the performance of this code is likely worse than that of the approach suggested by Michael Karcher, the code clearly and obviously reaches the desired result which is more important to me.

Here is some example code, testing a custom `strtol` implementation:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef PAGE_SIZE
#define PAGE_SIZE 16384
#endif

long mystrtol(const char *restrict, char **restrict, int);

/* a signal handler that makes testpage writable and then returns */
static void *testpage;
static void
maptestpage(int sig)
{
    mprotect(testpage, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
}

/*
 * Call mystrtol() on the given input with a page fault after the given
 * number of characters.  Print an error if the return value is not
 * equal to what strtol() says it should be.
 */
static void
test_mystrtol(const char *str, size_t off)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    long num;
    int res;
    char *data, *cpy, *endptr;

    data = mmap(NULL, 2*PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return;
    }

    cpy = data + PAGE_SIZE - off;
    strcpy(cpy, str);
    mprotect(data + PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_NONE);
    testpage = data + PAGE_SIZE;

    sa.sa_handler = maptestpage;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    res = sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
    if (res != 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        goto end;
    }

    num = mystrtol(cpy, &endptr, 10);
    signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);

    if (num != ...) {
        /* ... */
    }

end:    munmap(data, 2*PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following code, both locally in WSL2 (which basically is a real Linux kernel running in a Hyper-V VM) and on godbolt.org:

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec tsa, tsb;
    int my_fd = open("/proc/self/exe", O_RDONLY);
    char* mapping = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, my_fd, 0);
    volatile int x = mapping[0] + mapping[4096];
    munmap(mapping + 4096, 4096);
    mmap(mapping + 4096, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, 0, 0);
    volatile int y = mapping[4096];
    munmap(mapping + 4096, 4096);
    mmap(mapping + 4096, 4095, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, my_fd, 4096);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsa);  // prefetch clock_gettime
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsa);
    volatile int x2 = mapping[0];
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsb);
    printf("first page (no fault): %d ns\n", (tsb.tv_nsec + 1000000000 - tsa.tv_nsec) % 999999999);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsa);
    volatile int y2 = mapping[4096];
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsb);
    printf("second page (fault?): %d ns\n", (tsb.tv_nsec + 1000000000 - tsa.tv_nsec) % 999999999);
}
```

The goal is to create a two-page mapping, and prime the filesystem cache (which likely is hot anyway on `/proc/self/exe`), then it will replace the second page by something else and restore the self-mapping. The first access to the second page is very slow, indicating that the re-mapping of the filesystem cache happens on first use in the page-fault handler, not already on the mmap call.

The output at godbolt looks something like this:

```
first page (no fault): 76 ns
second page (fault?): 1032 ns
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems very unlikely for the kernel to be able to optimize.  A couple things: To make the accesses to shared memory `volatile`, use `volatile char *mapping = mmap(...)`.  Using `volatile` local variables forces just forces the compiler to store to stack space.  The thing stopping it from using the same value twice for `mapping[4096]` (instead of doing another load) is the non-inline function calls in between the accesses, which could be modifying the same object that `char *mapping` points to, as far as it knows.  (in this case by changing which page backs it.)

Comment: Also, `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is normally used with `MAP_PRIVATE`, although [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) does document that Linux has supported `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED` since Linux kernel 2.4.  Shared anonymous pages are apparently a thing, like staying shared across fork, and also it's possible to map the same physical page twice with it? (https://bpowers.net/posts/shared-anon-pages/) But we're not doing that, and it seems complicated and surprising.   And `fd = -1` is recommended for `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, although Linux doesn't enforce that.  (Some other OSes do.)

Comment: Perhaps `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED|MADV_RANDOM)` to hint the kernel not to prefault the pages?  But IDK if that sticks across an mmap(MAP_FIXED), and would probably be useless afterwards; you might as well just do the access right away since those won't evict before returning something already pre-faulted.  (Only `MADV_FREE` does that.)